# Dumb question, $A \subset B$, what is $A - B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know this is a super dumb question, but if you had a little set $A$ contained in a bigger set $B$, what the set difference $A - B$?

$B - A$ is well defined and I can visualize it in my head ( donut ), but I can't viualize anything the other way around. Please help!

Comment: Visualize it the same way as $B-A$, but rather than imagining the inner circle is missing(giving you a donut), imagine that the outer circle is missing. Since the inner circle is completely contained in the outer one, there is nothing left after you take the big circle away. Thus $A-B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just $\{x\in A \colon x\not\in B\}=\emptyset$

Answer (score 3):

The set $A-B$ is defined as $\{x:x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in B\}$.  If $A\subset B$, then every element of $A$ is an element of $B$, so $A-B=\emptyset$ (no $x$ satisfies its definition).  More generally, $A-B$ is $A$ with $A\cap B$ removed from $A$ (and in this case, $A\cap B$ is all of $A$).

Answer (score 0):

$A-B$ is the set of all elements in $A$ that are not in $B$.   However, as all of the elements in $A$ *are* in $B$ (because $A\subset B$), therefore there are no elements in $A-B$.

$$\begin{align}\because \;&\; A\subset B \\ \therefore \;&\; A-B = \emptyset \end{align}$$